# Cropped off? Cut off? cut out?

Tags: word-usage

Say you're watching a video on YouTube, and the person is filming themselves, but the camera can't get their head in the video, because there isn't enough room on the screen. What would you say? let's say now you're printing out a page and the page doesn't print out with all the stuff it was supposed to have what would you say in that situation too?

> The camera cropped off/cut out/cut off the person's head?
>   The words were cropped off/cut out/cut off on the printout?

Answer (score 3):

*Cut off* works in those examples.

*Cropped **off*** is not a normal collocation. Normally we'd say *cropped **out***.

*Cut out* can sometimes work in these instances, but it has a different meaning and the ambiguity can make it necessary to choose a different word.

**Unambiguous**:
*Hey, where am I? Our whole team's here, but you cut me out of the picture!*

Here, the meaning is clearly *you cropped the picture in such a way that I no longer appear in it*.

*I cut her face out of the photograph and put it in a locket*.

Here we see the other meaning of *cut out*: "to remove something from a larger piece by cutting" ([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cut-out)). In this case, the part of the photograph that showed the woman's face was removed from the rest of the photograph.

**Ambiguous**:
*Part of this picture is good, but the rest stinks. Cut the flowers out of it.*

Are the flowers the good part of the picture, which should be removed from their ugly context, or are they making an otherwise nice looking picture look bad?